# Flink sql api - how to read kafka event which in turn has a location to s3

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to using flink sql to read data from kafka topic. We have a pattern where, if payload size if greater than 1MB, we upload the payload to s3 and in the kafka event send a location to s3.
I have a flink table like this

```
 CREATE TABLE table_name
(
    header VARCHAR,
    contentJson varchar,
    `timestamp` timestamp_ltz
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'kafka',
      'topic' = 'topic-name',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:29092,localhost:39092',
      'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
      );
```

Here the `contentJson` field can be actual json like

```
{
"stack": "stuff"
}
```

or it could be a string like `/some-bucket/some-folder/actual-file.json`

How do I use

```
insert into final_table
select 
JSON_VALUE(header, '$.some-path-json') as value-1,
JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$.some-path-json') as value-2 -- this works if the `contentJson` is actual json and not a point to s3 bucket.
from table_name
```

Question is can do all this with flink sql or should I convert the table to stream and process the message where i can call aws s3 api to get the data is `contentJson` is a s3 location

Answer (score 0):

The right solution to these kinds of problems would be to use [lookup join](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-table-store-docs-master/docs/development/lookup-join/), unfortunately that's not supported for the `filesystem` connector.

I think the best solution right now would be to do it with the `DataStream` API.

I have written this example to show a possible solution, but I would advise against using it for the following reasons:

- both table contents will be kept in Flinks state forever by default - [more info](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#regular-joins)
- it requires the file to be already read by Flink to its state (you can set the interval to read files using `source.monitor-interval`)
- the file you want to read must be in the path you specify for the `filesystem` table

```
CREATE TABLE kafka_source (
  json_or_file STRING
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  -- ...
)

CREATE TABLE file_source (
  content STRING,
  `file.path` STRING NOT NULL METADATA
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'filesystem',
  'path' = 'file:///tmp/test',
  'format' = 'raw'
)

SELECT 
  header, 
  CASE WHEN file_source.content IS NULL THEN 
    JSON_VALUE(kafka_source.json_or_file, '$.key') 
  ELSE 
    JSON_VALUE(file_source.content, '$.key') 
  END 
FROM 
  kafka_source FULL 
  OUTER JOIN file_source ON file_source.`file.path` = kafka_source.json_or_file 
WHERE 
  JSON_VALUE(
    kafka_source.json_or_file, '$.key'
  ) IS NOT NULL 
  OR file_source.content IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. My initial solution might be with datastream and table api mix